# How do I install _"64-bit Power PC Ubuntu 14.04 "Trusty Tahr" Minimal CD" on my MeeGoPad Stick T01 64-bit?

Tags: boot, usb, iso, ubuntu-minimal

The MeeGoPad Stick came with Windows 8.1 and Android that I also would like to remove and run Ubuntu only. I cant find a way to mount the `mini.iso` file to a bootable usb. I am using Rufus 2.1.649 and when i try to mount the `iso` it says

> This version of rufus only supports bootable ISOs bassed on bootmgr,
>   EFI, Grub4DOS,Grub 2, isolinux, or WinPE. This ISO doesn't appear to
>   use either...

On [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) web page  it says :

> Unlike other iso images available on this site, older versions of this
>   image mini.iso do not work with the USB stick installation method.

And I don't know where to go from there. I am also using a Windows 7 computer to configure everything. I want to start with minimal CD because I want it very bare-bones with `lxde-core` install, I dont need a whole package. I have mounted ubuntu server on usb with success so I know rufus works, I'm just not wanting to use that version.

1. I need help mounting iso to bootable usb.
2. I need help to start boot on Stick
3. I want to remove Windows 8.1 and Android OS

Comment: I appreciate the advice on the flavor of ubuntu but i really need help to mount the iso, then to start the boot

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to be possible to use the `dd` command to create the bootable USB, though you will need a working Linux system to run it! The page you linked has links to [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073) about using dd to make the bootable usb, although I couldn't see the command example.

You'll need to know what the device name for the usb, and other internal disks, in the form `/dev/sdx`.

Then your `dd` command will be:

```
dd if=/path/to/iso-file of=/dev/sdx
```

Replacing sdx with the correct letters to refer to your USB, be very careful with this command, if you type the wrong device name, you can overwrite your entire operating system.